# Keep getting ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR when saving to file

Tags: javascript, apache, nginx, sftp

*The Problem:* 
I edit an asset file such has .js or .css via my code editor Sublime Editor 3. I then save those files to the server via an SFTP plugin on sublime. Then when I refresh the live website to view changes from my chrome browser (I have a plugin that flushes the browser cache so I see new changes.) I sometimes get a error on the chrome console that reads:

```
net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200
```

Where the browser is not served the requested file. When I check my log file for Apache I see the following:

```
[alert] 657967#657967: *188534 pread() read only 7497 of 7498
```

My server is setup with Nginx running as a Web Server and Reverse Proxy for Apache.

How can I make it so that Nginx does not fail server the requested files even though they were just edited. Maybe sending back cache until it updates the new changes. Please advise because it is driving me nuts and I have no idea how to overcome it.

My workflow for JavaScript consists of me writing code and refreshing the live site to view web console on chrome. I need to be able to view the changes I made from the server via browser. I don't like local environments. I tried to google this topic many times with no luck so any help would be much appreciated.